# Why Can't the data pointed by pointer saved after executing the function?

Tags: arrays, c, string, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am confused that after I store the address of a string array in a pointer inside a function, it does not return me the string but something looks like an address. Since p has already stored the address of an array, why wouldn't it print the corresponding string?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10
void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last, int size);
int main()
{
  char word[SIZE][40];
  char first[40], last[40];
  int i, size;
  printf("Enter size: \n");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  printf("Enter %d words: \n", size);
  for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    scanf("%s", word[i]);
  findMinMaxStr(word, first, last, size);
  printf("First word = %s, Last word = %s\n", first, last);
  return 0;
}

void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last,int size)
{
  int i;
  first = word[0];
  last = word[0];
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(strcmp(last,word[i])<0)
      last = word[i];
    if(strcmp(first,word[i])>0)
      first = word[i];
  }
}
```

If I add a printf statement inside the function:

```
void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last,int size)
{
  int i;
  first = word[0];
  last = word[0];
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(strcmp(last,word[i])<0)
      last = word[i];
    if(strcmp(first,word[i])>0)
      first = word[i];
  }
    printf("first : %s, last: %s\n",first,last);
}
```

It can print the string right.

Answer (score 0):

C uses pass-by-value for function parameters, and the pointers themselves are passed by value. In other words, you can change the content pointed to by the address stored in the pointer variables, but cannot change the pointer variables themselves.

Inside the function, change

```
  last = word[i];  //updates the pointer itself, which will not reflect in the caller
```

to

```
  strcpy(last, word[i]);  // copy the content to the memory pointed to by pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments in C are **copies** of what are passed, so modifycation (assignment) of them don't affect what are passed.

In this case, pointers converted from arrays are passed, so simply changing the arguments doesn't seem good.

To copy strings, you should use `strcpy()` instead of assigning pointers.

```
void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last,int size)
{
  int i;
  strcpy(first,word[0]);
  strcpy(last,word[0]);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(strcmp(last,word[i])<0)
      strcpy(lasy,word[i]);
    if(strcmp(first,word[i])>0)
      strcpy(first,word[i]);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can store pointers in loops and copy the resulting string after the loop.

```
void findMinMaxStr(char word[][40], char *first, char *last,int size)
{
  int i;
  char* first_ptr = word[0];
  char* last_ptr = word[0];
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(strcmp(last_ptr,word[i])<0)
      last_ptr = word[i];
    if(strcmp(first_ptr,word[i])>0)
      first_ptr = word[i];
  }
  strcpy(first,first_ptr);
  strcpy(last,last_ptr);
}
```